# Parse XML file with more than 1 root element in R

Tags: r, xml

Using R, I would like to parse a series of XML files, all of which contain more than 1 root element and look like this:

```
<block>
    <item>Here's an item</item>
    <item>Here's another item</item>
    <item>Here's an item with some sub-items
        <subitem>one</subitem>
        <subitem>two</subitem>
    </item>
</block>
<anotherblock>
    <item>Here's an item</item>
    <item>Here's another item</item>
    <item>Here's an item with some sub-items
        <subitem>one</subitem>
        <subitem>two</subitem>
    </item>
</anotherblock>
```

Using read_xml it's not surprise I'm getting an error ("Extra content at the end of the document").

**Assuming that I cannot change the process generating the log files**, anyone have a smart idea how to process the files efficiently?

Thank you, Philipp

Comment: These are invalid XML files. You can try `read_html` will wrap the nodes in an explicit `<body>` tag. That way you can still parse the data. Or you could manually paste your own surrounding root element if you read the data in as just a string first.

Comment: By definition, XML files are well-formed adhering to W3C rule which includes one root. This markup is not XML. Check source to why you received such a fragment.